# How to redirect from SpringFormController based on input parameters?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Here's the basic requirement:

1. An http request is received by page A that may have parameters defined.
2. If parameters are defined, page A processes the request and automatically forwards to page B. If parameters are not defined, display page A with a form for the user to fill in and submit. On submit, process the request and forward to page B.

Basically, I want to bypass the need for the user to enter data via onSubmit() if the data has already been provided as input parameters to page A. How can I do this?

Page A and B are implemented by extending the (deprecated) SimpleFormController. One way I've done this before is to place a "hidden" page (A′) that accepts the request and, if parameters are defined, processes the data and redirects to B. If the parameters are not provided, then I redirect to A where the processing is done.

This doesn't seem efficient to me, as it duplicates a lot of the processing code.

I'm not providing any code, since it doesn't easily explicate the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand but you want a method in controller that will direct based on information provided.

Here is something i knocked up quickly that i hope will help solve the problem:

```
@RequestMapping("/pageA/{parameter}")
public String displayPageA(Model model, @PathVariable String parameter) {
   if(parameter == null)
   {
      model.addAttribute("your_form", new YourForm());
      return "pageA";
   }
   else {
      return "redirect:/pageB/"+parameter;  // this is if you want the parameter passed on
   }
}
```